# Can't get rid of warning c6385 while trying to free dynamic memory (2D matrix) c

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I've been breaking my head over this issue, VScode gives me this weird warning about malloc calculations

```
c6385 "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'temp':  the readable size is 'sizeof(int *)*width_flag' bytes, but '16' bytes may be read"
```

And again with

```
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp':  the writable size is 'sizeof(int *)*width_flag' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written"
```

I think I am doing mallloc and free by the book and still this comes up

the code

```
poolList_t* pools_f(pixmat** mtrx, image_t image, poolList_t* pools, int width_flag) {
int i, j, size;
int** temp = NULL;
pix_t* root = NULL;
co_t center;
if (sizeof(int*) * width_flag > 0)
    temp = malloc(sizeof(int*) * width_flag); //alocating memory for matrix which will contain 1/0 for each blue/non-blue pixel
if (temp) {
    if (sizeof(int) * image.height > 0)
        for (i = 0;i < width_flag; i++) {
            temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * image.height);
        }// allocate memory to temp color signed matrix
}

if (temp != 0)
{

    for (i = 0; i < image.height; i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < width_flag;j++) {
            if (mtrx[j][i].color.r == 155 && mtrx[j][i].color.g == 190 && mtrx[j][i].color.b == 245) { // Registering blue and non-blue pixel to 2d matrix named temp
                temp[j][i] = 1;
            }
            else {
                temp[j][i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < image.height;i++) {
        for (j = 0;j < width_flag;j++) {
            if (temp[j][i] == 1) { //Going over all the pixels in the matrix and checking if it is blue or not
                size = 1;
                temp[j][i] = 0;
                pix_insert(&root, mtrx[j][i].cordinate); //saving the blue pixel to the head of linked list
                segment(root, mtrx, temp, image, i, j, &size); //entering to Image segmentation function to find adjacent blue pixels
                if (size > 9) {
                    center = pool_middle(root, size);
                    pool_insert(&pools, size, center, root); //saving the pool to linked list ONLY if it has size of 10 or more
                }
            }
            deallocpix(&root); //deallocting the memory of the pixel's linked list
        }
    }
    for (i = 0;i < width_flag;i++) {
        free(temp[i]); //deallocating temp matrix memory
    }
    free(temp);
    return pools;
} else
    return pools;
}
```

the structs I use

```
typedef struct pool { //pools' list extructed of bmp
int size; //the number of pixels that combine the pool
co_t pool_center;
pix_t* pix; //list of pool pixels
struct pool* next;
}poolList_t;

typedef struct pixel { //list of pixels
co_t p;
struct pixel* next;
}pix_t;

typedef struct { //pixel's coordinates
int x;
int y; 
 }co_t;

typedef struct { // struct to contain each pixel color & coordinates
color_t color;
co_t coordinate;
} pixmat;
```

Comment: Not related to the error `for (i = 0; i < image.height; i++) { for (j = 0;j < width_flag;j++) { if (mtrx[j][i]` is very poorly performing code since it runs around touching RAM memory all over the place and not giving the CPU a chance to store anything in data cache. It should be `for (i = 0; i<width_flag; i++) for (j = 0; j<image.height; j++) if(mtrx[i][j]` Iterate over the inner-most dimension before increasing the outermost one by 1, not the other way around.

Comment: Please show at which lines __exactly__ you get these warnings.

Comment: Also to increase performance further, consider using 2D arrays instead: `int (*temp)[image.height] = malloc( sizeof(int[width_flag][image.height]) );
...
free(temp);`

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays of pointers adds unnecesary indirection. Use **array pointers**

```
if(width_flag && image.height)
{
    int (*temp)[image.height];

    temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * width_flag); //alocating memory for matrix which will contain 1/0 for each blue/non-blue pixel
}
```